# stream plot 2d cross section

Tags: plotting, differential-equations, vector

Let say I have some 3d equation, something like

```
dx/dt=y-x

dy/dt=z(y-x)

dz/dt=y-z
```

I'd like to do a stream plot that is a cross section for some fixed z. Is there a way to do this?

Comment: I'm not quite sure what you mean;  since $dz/dt \neq 0$, the stream lines will generally not lie in a plane of fixed $z$.  A naive "cross section" would then just be a bunch of points, corresponding to the intersections of each 3D streamline with the fixed-$z$ plane.   Can you give an example of a plot somewhere else on the web that could help us visualize what you want?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You may use `SliceVectorPlot3D`.

```
Manipulate[
 SliceVectorPlot3D[{y - x, z (y - x), y - z}, 
   {y == 0, z == a}, {x, -1, 1}, {y, -1, 1}, {z, -1, 1}],
 {{a, -1}, -1, 1}]
```

[image]

Hope this helps.

Comment: Interesting, I didn't know you could do that with the Sliced Vector Plot. This is sort of what I was looking for. Thank you!

Answer (score 5):

By plotting the projection of your vectors on an *x-y*-plane, like so:

```
u = y - x
v[z_] = z (y - x)
Manipulate[StreamPlot[{u, v[z]}, {x, -1, 1}, {y, -1, 1}], {z, -1, 1}]
```

Is this what you're looking for?

Comment: Projection is a nice idea, but if the lines of `StreamPlot` represent trajectories over time, then `z` would be changing throughout that time altering the vector field & trajectories.  While the lines have little significance, it seems to me the projected direction field has some meaning.